# Magento 2 New Order Event: get Customer's telephone

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

I have an observer for every order status change, and another for every new order. In both observers I need to retrieve the customer's phone number. In order-status-change this happens as follows:

```
$phone = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

However in new-order, none of the below succeed. They all return `null`. Why does this happen? What could I do?

```
$order->getCustomerPhone();
$order->getBillingAddress();
$order->getShippingAddress();
$order->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
```

Comment: You can try to observer the sale orders address save event.

Comment: can you please tell me which event you are using for order status change?

Comment: Sure. It's `sales_order_save_after` for both of them and I distinguish the case according to the path

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau you mean that my event occurs before the phone is saved on the address? Which exact event are you referring? I can't find any  event named `sales_order_address_save`

Comment: its a `customer_address_save_after`

Comment: I'm afraid that if I replace event `sales_order_save_after`  with `customer_address_save_after` for new orders, I get an error and the checkout can't be completed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick that worked. (The event remained unchanged: `sales_order_save_after`)

```
private function getPhoneFromObserver(Observer $observer)
{
    $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    foreach( $data['addresses'] as $addr ) {
        if( $addr['telephone'] !== null ) {
            return $addr['telephone'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `<event name="sales_order_address_save_after">` in which order id already stored (if you need it). Just check is it billing or shipping address:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
/** @see \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_getEventData() */
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $address */
$address = $event->getDataObject();
/** @var int $orderId */
$orderId = $address->getParentId();
$addressType = $address->getAddressType();

switch ($addressType) {
    case Address::TYPE_BILLING:
        // Do something with billing address
        break;
    case Address::TYPE_SHIPPING:
        // Do something with shipping address
        break;
    default:
        /**
         * This is a not usual case, when address type is not in one of this types: billing or shipping
         */
        break;
}
```

this event is triggered each time order address was saved. So you should add an additional check: is your info (telephone) was already stored recently or not?

Comment: When exactly is this triggered? Only on orders from frontend? What about when a customer makes an order without saving a new address?
I also need the event in case of admin panel's order

Comment: @IriniKoutaki as you can see it's related with a `sales_order_address`, not with a customers address, so it will work in any case when an order was placed, both on frontend and backend. PS: `sales_order_address` is a different entity saved with an order each time to store a customers data on the moment when the order was placed.